# is Pseudometric compact space bounded?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Basically i need to prove that a specific given space $X$ with the topology induced by a pseudometric $d$ is not compact. To do that i demonstrated that it is not bounded, but i'm not sure it is sufficient.

I know that if I have a metric space $X$ with the induced topology, $X$ bounded $\Rightarrow$ totally bounded $\Rightarrow$ bounded, so if it is not bounded then it is not compact.

Does this sequence hold for pseudometric too?

Comment: Have you tried imitating the proof for metric spaces?

Comment: Bounded does not imply totally bounded for general metric spaces. The classic example is the closed unit ball in an infinite-dimensional Banach space. Clearly bounded, but if it were also totally bounded it would be compact and it's a well-known fact that this is only possible if the Banach space is finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

In a pseudometric space $X$, it is also true that if the space is compact, then it is bounded. That's because, if $X$ is unbounded and $x\in X$, then the set$$\{B_n(x)\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$$is on open cover without a finite subcover.